# How to use the map::find() method for a nested map?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a `map<int, map<int,int>> mymap;`

How do I use the `find()` method for nested `map`s like this?

If I have `map<int,int> mymap, mymap.find(key)` it gives a result. But what about nested `map`s for more than 1 key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also note that there is [`std::map::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at).

It throws `std::out_of_range` if a matching key doesn't exists, but the usage in your case is simple.

```cpp
auto value = mymap.at(key1).at(key2);
```

If you are not sure keys exists you can catch this exception or go with approach in [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70217924/7582247).

Answer (score 3):

`mymap.find()` will search for the 1st key and return an iterator to a `std::pair` containing that key's associated value, which is a `std::map`.

Then `find()` on that `std::map` will search for the second key, returning an iterator to a `std::pair` containing its associated value, which is an `int`.

For example:

```cpp
map<int, map<int,int>> mymap;
auto it1 = mymap.find(key1);
if (it1 != mymap.end()) {
    auto it2 = it1->second.find(key2);
    if (it2 != it1->second.end()) {
        // use it2->second as needed...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After

```
auto entry = mymap.find(key);
```

you discover that `entry` is an iterator to a `std::pair` containing the (`const`!) key and the value, the latter in your case is yet another map, so:

```
auto subEntry = entry->second.find(subKey)
```

(Provided, of course, `entry != mymap.end()`!)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice is to provide a tool to handle such cases.

So [solution provided by Remy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70217924/1387438) should take a form of helper function or universal template:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Key>
auto optional_at(T& x, Key&& key)
    -> std::optional<typename T::mapped_type>
{
    auto it = x.find(std::forward<Key>(key));
    if (it == x.end()) 
        return {};
    return it->second;
}

template<typename T, typename Key, typename ...Keys>
auto optional_at(T& x, Key&& key, Keys&&...keys)
    -> decltype(optional_at(x[key], std::forward<Keys>(keys)...))
{
    auto it = x.find(std::forward<Key>(key));
    if (it != x.end()) 
        return optional_at(it->second, std::forward<Keys>(keys)...);
    return {};
}

//---------------------
int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::map<int, std::string>> m{
        {1, {{1, "one-one"}}},
        {2, {{1, "two-one"}, {2, "two-two"}}}
    };
    
    ...
    print(std::cout, optional_at(m, 1, 2)) << '\n';
    print(std::cout, optional_at(m, 2, 1)) << '\n';
    print(std::cout, optional_at(m, 2, 2)) << '\n';
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TTnsKf49a)

Then when this is used intention is clear and simple.